# can't install iso linux from eays2boot usb stick

Tags: linux, usb, live-usb

i set up a usb with easy2boot to try live or install iso's from it, copied some iso's to the stick in the linux folder, but when I try to install a live system of debian, it starts briefly and then breaks off.

in the linux menu i see debian-11.5.0-amd64-dvd-1.iso ***not contiguous*** after select i see a message to defrag all files. when i start the same iso from dvd i can install that iso, i try download ubuntu and get same error

how do i get it to work or is there another program to create easy usb from which I can install and try different iso's ?

Comment: It is by far easiest to clone from one single iso file to a USB stick, use it and then clone another iso file (to the same or another USB stick). This works with hybrid iso files, and most linux iso files are hybrid iso files. You can use any cloning tool for this purpose, and I recommend a tool with a final checkpoint to help double-check that you clone to the correct drive. [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) works well in Ubuntu and Debian. - There are tools to make multiboot USB sticks, but it will soon get more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

Double-click the file MAKE_THIS_DRIVE_CONTIGUOUS.cmd which is in the root of the E2B drive (it normally tells you to do this when a file is not contiguous).

Answer (score 1):

Some types of payload files need to be contiguous in order to work correctly (this applies to all types of E2B USB drives – Removable UFD or Fixed-disk). E2B will warn you if they are not contiguous when you try to boot from them, but they may still boot correctly.

To avoid any ‘not contiguous’ error messages from E2B or agFM, double-click on the:
\MAKE_THIS_DRIVE_CONTIGUOUS.cmd
file on the E2B USB drive to run WinContig and make all E2B files in \ and under _ISO on the USB drive contiguous – OR – run RMPrepUSB – CTRL+F2 to run WinContig on the whole drive instead.

You can copy the *.cmd files from _ISO\docs\WINCONTIG to the root of the E2B USB drive if you wish. Then you can double-click on any one of them to run them.

```
\MAKE_ISO_FOLDER_CONTIGUOUS.cmd
\MAKE_ROOT_FOLDER_CONTIGUOUS.cmd
\MAKE_THIS_DRIVE_CONTIGUOUS.cmd (works on \_ISO and files in \ – i.e. runs WinContig twice)
```

[https://easy2boot.xyz/create-your-website-with-blocks/make-files-contiguous/][1](https://easy2boot.xyz/create-your-website-with-blocks/make-files-contiguous/)
https://rmprepusb.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-make-large-files-contiguous-on.html